# Combining two JSONS in a dataframe in scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I'm working with a dataframe at below. What I want to do is combine the JSONS of column `JSON1` and `JSON2` if the `FLAG` = Y and insert the values into `JSON2`.

```
+--------------------+-------------------------+---------+-----------+--------+--------------------+
|    JSON1           |                    MISC1|    MISC2|    MISC3  |    FLAG|         JSON2     
|
+--------------------+-------------------------+---------+-----------+--------+--------------------+
|{"v1":"3","v2":"4"} |         {"Number":100.0}|        1|       0330|       Y|{"v3":"5","v4": "6"}|
|{"v1":"3","v2":"4"} |         {"Number":120.0}|        1|       0380|       N|{"v3":"5","v4": "6"}|
|{"v1":"3","v2":"4"} |         {"Number":100.0}|        1|       7203|       Y|{"v3":"5","v4": "6"}|
|{"v1":"3","v2":"4"} |         {"Number":100.0}|        1|       1520|       Y|{"v3":"5","v4": "6"}|
|{"v1":"3","v2":"4"} |         {"Number":100.0}|        1|       1600|       N|{"v3":"5","v4": "6"}|
|{"v1":"3","v2":"4"} |         {"Number":100.0}|        1|       1793|       Y|{"v3":"5","v4": "6"}|
|{"v1":"3","v2":"4"} |         {"Number":100.0}|        1|       1797|       Y|{"v3":"5","v4": "6"}|
|{"v1":"3","v2":"4"} |         {"Number":100.0}|        1|       1670|       Y|{"v3":"5","v4": "6"}|
|{"v1":"3","v2":"4"} |         {"Number":132.0}|        1|       0790|       Y|{"v3":"5","v4": "6"}|
|{"v1":"3","v2":"4"} |         {"Number":100.0}|        1|       0770|       Y|{"v3":"5","v4": "6"}|
|{"v1":"3","v2":"4"} |         {"Number":100.0}|        1|       1670|       Y|{"v3":"5","v4": "6"}|
+--------------------+-------------------------+---------+-----------+--------+--------------------+
```

When I say combine, I mean the combined JSON would be:
`{"v1": "3", "v2":"4", "v3": "5","v4": "6"}`. If the keys overlap, the values in JSON2 should take priority.

Is there any easy way to do this in one statement? What I know so far is to do something like this:

```
someDF.withColumn("JSON2", when(col("FLAG") === "Y",
{
          val JSON2 = scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull(col("JSON2").toString()).get.asInstanceOf[Map[String,String]]
          val JSON1 = scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull(col("JSON1").toString()).get.asInstanceOf[Map[String,String]]
          val newJSON = mutable.Map[String, String]()
          newJSON ++= JSON2

          JSON1.foreach(kv =>
          {
            if(newJSON.get(kv._1) == null)
              newJSON + (kv._1 -> kv._2)
            else
              newJSON(kv._1) = kv._2
          })
          newJSON
}
))
```

However, I keep erroring out at the JSON2 line due to a `None.get`. I am not sure why these columns aren't being fetched or if there's a much easier way to do this that I'm not seeing, but I could use a second pair of eyes on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, You appear to be on a very old version of Scala. `scala.util.parsing.json` was deprecated and removed years ago in favor of external libraries. [Circe](https://github.com/circe/circe) would be a common one used today.

```
import io.circe.parser

val JSON2 = parser.parse("""{"v1":"3","v2":"4"}""").toOption.get
val JSON1 = parser.parse("""{"v3":"5","v4":"6","v2":"8"}""").toOption.get

JSON1.deepMerge(JSON2) // : Json = {"v1" : "3", "v2" : "4", "v3" : "5", "v4" : "6"}
```

Comment: Sorry, I typed in the JSON wrong here. Let me fix it. It's supposed to be  `{"v1":"3","v2":"4"}`.